# jpaTemplate how to autocommit...?

Tags: hibernate, spring, jpa

I am using JPA
i have setup transaction on service layer using @Transactional..
it is working fine..
but when i test Dao (Junit) transactions using JpaTemplate are not getting commited..  although same test with JdbcTemplate were getting comitted...

So how to enable auto-commit for JpaTemplate...?

Comment: just to check, are you calling methods on the services or on the DAO from your unit tests?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are calling you DAO's directly...

Do not attempt to configure auto-commit, it is not recommended. Instead, setup your test context like [described here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testcontext-tx).